# Would anyone have a suggestion why my function is not providing graphs with customized dots, but black dots instead?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

This is my function to create the colors:

```
create_color <- function(df){
  level <- create_level(df)
  colors <- list ()

  for (i in 1:length(level)) {
    ilevel <- level [i]
    
       if (any(grepl("5min", ilevel))) {
      colors[i] <- "#77003c"
    } else if (any(grepl("60min", ilevel))) {
      colors[i] <- "#9804e4"
    } else if (any(grepl("6h", ilevel))) {
      colors[i] <- "#bd7ebd"
    } else if (any(grepl("24h", ilevel))) {
      colors[i] <- "#a49787"
    } else {
      colors[i] <- "#000000"
    }
  }
  return (colors)
}
```

This is the plot function:

```
histo_plot_dotty <- function(df, min, max){
  colors <- create_color(df)
  ylabelling <- as.character(df[[1,3]])
  print(colors)
  level <- create_level(df)
  print(level)
  plot <- ggplot(df, aes (x = factor(key, level = level), y = values), fill = group_column2)+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 0.3, binpositions = "all", dotsize = 1)+
    scale_fill_manual (values = colors)+
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min, max), expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
    labs(title = "",
         x = "individual",
         y = paste0("(", ylabelling, ")","/FoV"),
         fill = "dosing") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -65, vjust = 0.5, hjust=0, size = 8),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))
  print(plot)
    print(plot)
    return(plot)
}
```

[this is what the dataframe that I apply both functions on looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn5AR.png)

I tried different versions of the create_color() function, where to include it into the plot function, extending the df dataframe by a color column instead and reading this with the scale_fill_manual() function, scale_colour_manual() instead of fill, including colour into the geom function and so on..

Answer (score 1):

We have to map `colors` to the `fill` aesthetic.
An example, with code adapted from the question:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris
colors <- c('red', 'blue')
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = factor(Species),
           y = Sepal.Width,
           fill = rep(colors, each = 75
                      )
           )
       ) +
    geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y",
                 stackdir = "center",
                 stackratio = 0.3,
                 binpositions = "all",
                 dotsize = 1
                 )
```

[image: dotplot with iris dataset and coloured dots]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I tried, but it didnt work , what am I missing? 
 ''' plot <- ggplot(df, aes (x = factor(key, level = level), y = values), fill = colors)+'''

The colors variable is a list containing as many hexcodes as single datapoints in the dataframe df

Comment: Hi, anmuena, I can only help so much without a proper reproducible example, which is impossible without sample data.

Please share at least a subset of the data. You can paste the output of `dput(df)` or maybe `dput(head(df, 10))`